# jQuery UI sortable and draggable. Getting the index of dragged element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am having a very specific problem, using jQuery UI sortable and dragable together. I want to be able to get the index/placement in the list of the newly dragged element. I am able to get this if I move the elements around inside the list.

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: ".sortable"
});
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    items: 'li',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        index = ui.item.index()+1;
        console.lo(index);
    },
    connectWith: ".sortableSub",
    appendTo: 'body',
}).disableSelection();
```

The code above works as it should, but if i do the same with the dragged element.

```
receive: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item.index());
},
```

using ui.item.index just returns 0, if i do the same in stop: instead of receive: it returns -1 instead, and this is no matter where it is dropped.

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution how to get the index of ADDED item in sortable list.

```
receive: function( event, ui ) {
  var newIndex = $(this).data("ui-sortable").currentItem.index()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: ".sortable"
});
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    items: 'li',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        index = ui.item.index()+1;
        console.log(index);
    },
    connectWith: ".sortableSub",
    appendTo: 'body',
}).disableSelection();

$( "#draggable" ).on( "dragcreate", function( event, ui ) {

  console.log(ui.item.index());
});
```

or try this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        var index = ui.item.index()+1;
         console.log(index);
    }
});
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    items: 'li',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        index = ui.item.index()+1;
        console.log(index);
    },
    connectWith: ".sortableSub",
    appendTo: 'body',
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Neither works or even writes anything in the console, but found another solution to my problem, where i needed the index number.

Comment: @JesperNielsen your console doesn't output anything because you have misspelled it. It  is supposed to be console.log(out), not console.lo(out). Hope that helps.

Comment: hey @JesperNielsen thanks muchly for raising a question on here, then complaining about an answer you were offered, then telling us you found a solution but not supplying a description or pointer for that solution. I just love it when people do that on forums. Live long and prosper.

Comment: This doesn't work because the 'create' event on a draggable is always passed an empty ui object. From the docs "Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other events."
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-create

Comment: It looks like the `stop` or `beforeStop` events on sortable() both work fine for this. I think the only reason the original code didn't work might be the `console.lo()` typo

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to get dragged item in `ui.sortable`.

On `Receive` function, Use `**ui.item.sortable.model**` to get the dragged object.

```
receive: function(event, ui) 
{
   console.log("Task No : " + ui.item.sortable.model.SID);
},
```

NOTE: My object has a property named SID.